# 2 Cards are drawn from a deck of cards. What is the probability of having drawn a black card OR an ace?

Tags: probability

I'm sure this question involves combinations, dividing the probabilities of each black card/ace over ${52}\choose{2}$ (for $2$ cards drawn) and adding them but I'm not getting the right answer. The given solution is: $\frac{183}{221}$.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the probability of drawing two cards which are red and not aces?

Comment: To get a bad draw, you are only choosing from a smaller set of cards.  the reds that aren't aces.

Comment: so that would be 52_C_(26-4) / 52_C_2?

Comment: @Andrew That would give a probability greater than $1$. And are there $4$ red aces?

Comment: You are still choosing only 2 cards, but from a smaller pool.  I was thinking 24 choose 2 for the numerator and subtracting that from 1, but with that method, I get $\frac{175}{221}$ so I don't have the right method.

Comment: I get $175/221$ too. Either the given solution is wrong, or you have transcribed the question incorrectly.

Comment: @turkeyhundt close!

Comment: Ahh, I see. Probably a typo in the error. Mind if I ask what your calculation was? You pointed out the probability is greater than 1 in my attempt, so clearly that was wrong. Do I divide 52 nCr 4 by 52 nC 2 and add that to 1/2 (for the red cards)? Not sure.

Comment: I'll add an answer...

Comment: Thanks! You're all a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the probability of drawing two cards that include a black card or an ace.  When you are looking for the probability where multiple events can trigger the desired outcome (black card OR ace, AT LEAST one of the dice is a six, etc) sometimes it is easier to find the probability of the opposite happening and subtracting that from 100%.

In this case, the opposite is drawing two cards that are red and not an ace.  There are 24 cards that fit this criteria, so the only way to not get a black card or ace is to get two cards, both of which were from those 24 cards.

$$1-\frac{24\choose2}{52\choose2}=\frac{175}{221}$$

Another way to think of it would be

$$\frac{{52\choose2}-{24\choose2}}{52\choose2}$$

Answer (score 0):

On same lines as turkeyhundt

We find the probability of opposite outcome

Drawing a red card which is not an ace has probability 24/52
Repeat this without replacement and the probability is (24-1)/(52-1)

So the required probability is 1-(24/52)(23/51)=175/221